# Confused about adding array from post to database

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a complicated array (at least it looks complicated to me). I have a form where you select a person, a start time and an end time. You can then add more people by clicking a + button. So I named the three select fields like "select_dancer[]" for an array.

When I print_r my results, it looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [month_year] => 2011-11
    [select_dancer] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [time_from] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12:00pm
            [1] => 1:00pm
        )

    [time_to] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12:30pm
            [1] => 1:30pm
        )
)
```

Basically, the key 0 is one person, and key 1 is another. Etc. I'm having trouble getting my head around adding this to the database. My table is basically: id, date, dancer, from, to. So I want it so I can "group" each key together and submit the values to the database.

If anyone could help me out, that would be great.

Comment: What type of database are you using? MySQL? What method are you using to interface the database? PDO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easier approach to the field grouping would be something like this in your HTML

```
<input name="dancer[0][id]" ...
<input name="dancer[0][time_from]" ...
<input name="dancer[0][time_to]" ...
```

As each group is added, increment the number in the first square-brackets.

Your resulting `$_POST` array would then look like

```
Array
(
    [month_year] => 2011-11
    [dancer] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1,
            [time_from] => 12:00pm
            [time_to] => 12.30pm
        )
        [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [time_from] => 1:00pm
            [time_to] => 1:30pm
        )
    )
)
```

You can then iterate the `$_POST['dancer']` array for each group of values, eg (very simplified)

```
foreach ($_POST['dancer'] as $dancer) {
    if (!isset($dancer['id'], $dancer['time_from'], $dancer['time_to'])) {
        throw new Exception('All fields are required');
    }

    $id       = $dancer['id'];
    $timeFrom = $dancer['time_from'];
    $timeTo   = $dancer['time_to'];
}
```

Comment: +1 - I did not know HTML supported multidimensional arrays in forms!

Comment: @AndrewHeath HTML does not, it just allows the syntax that PHP (and .NET) can parse as an array / list

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks Phil. Exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If each of element `select_dancer`, `time_from`, `time_to` has the same array size, you can easily check for any of that and do loop using it:

**WARNING: UNTESTED CODE**

```
foreach($post_array['select_dancer'] as $key => $value)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO dance_table(date, dancer, from, to) ";
    $sql .= "VALUES('{$wherever_you_got_the_date}', '{$value}',";
    $sql .= "'" . $post_array['time_from'][$key] . "', ";
    $sql .= "'" . $post_array['time_from'][$key] . "')";
}
```

Comment: That's not pseudo-code, that's PHP code and dangerous PHP code at that!

Comment: @Silent: You have the basic premise, just missing the data validation piece, as Phil was pointing out. Going straight from form post vars to mysql will get you in hot water.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($mydata["select_dancer"]); $i++)
{
    $insert = "insert into mytable (date, dancer, from to) values ($mydata['month_year'], $mydata['select_dancer'][$i], $mydata['time_from'][$i], $mydata['time_to'][$i])";
    do_sql_insert($insert);
}
```

With this, you're vulnerable to injection attacks and the chance that a particular dancer doesn't have a represented index in every sub-array. Go with what @Phil wrote if you can.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST[select_dancer] as $key => $value) {
   $sql = "insert into table set dancer=$value,from='{$_POST['time_from'][$key]}',to={$_POST['time_to'][$key]}';"
  //execute the SQL ...
}
```

of course in real life got to deal will protecting against SQL injection etc, but the principle of accessing the arrays is the same